# How to write a program without window which can run under BitDefender?

Tags: c++, c, security

I found that BitDefender is very strict!

I can't write a win32 program which has no window that can run under BitDefender2012.

Can somebody write a c/c++ program that has no window and run under BitDefender2012?

Thank you

Comment: I have bitdefender 2012, and I have no problems coding with C++ whatsoever: Qt, MSVC, Embarcadero studio, and never did I have a problem with console applications.

Comment: What do you mean cannot run? What errors do you get?

Comment: TO:SingerOfTheFall -> i mean no window (no console window and win32 window , it is a backstage program)

Comment: To:RedX ->Bitdefender says it is a virus.

Comment: @wxfengyun, sorry, I have misunderstood you

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall  : Never Mind, my question is not very clearly.

Comment: This is quite ambiguous, so please clarify which is the case: You want to write a program that actively interacts with BitDefender, or are You just making some program that gets flagged as a virus by BitDefender for some reason?

Comment: @Vinska: I just write a c program for practising, this program just open a txt file and write some chars into it.This program without any window,it is a backstage program.But Bitdefender says it is a virus, so confused me.

Comment: It might be the case that Your program is doing something that upsets BD. Could You write the name/virus type identifier that BD detects Your program to be?

Comment: @Vinska: It is just a very very simple program, it has the only identifier to others is it has no window.Just this reason upsets BD.You can try by yourself to write any c/c++ program that has no window, I think BD will detects it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,refer to it's site and download SDK to develop as you want, another thing is run it in command line.

take a look at http://www.bitdefender.com/oem/